# Displaying the entire row after searching

Tags: php, mysql

So I can search the whole database but i need a way to change the $db_tb_atr_name="location" to all columns. I need to search for any keyword and return the whole row. Right now all that returns is the location. I do not know how to change my code to make this happen.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="megan";
$db_password="megan";
$db_name="megan";
$db_tb_name="user";
$db_tb_atr_name="location";

 mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
 mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
CONCAT(id_user,fname,lname,location,email,phone_number,username) LIKE '%".$query."%'");

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
 echo "<li>";
 echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
 echo "</li><hr/>";
}
 echo "</ol>";

 mysql_close();
 }
 ?>
```

If i change the $db_tb_atr_name to $db_tb_name it wont work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Try something like this:

```
$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE CONCAT(id_user,fname,lname,location,email,phone_number,username) LIKE '%".$query."%'");

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<li>";
    echo substr(implode(",", $data_fetch), 0,160);
    echo "</li><hr/>";
}
echo "</ol>";
```

I switched your mysql_fetch_array, to mysql_fetch_assoc. Now you can have a more organized and associate response.

Also, I imploded your $data_fetch, which means it is joining your different columns together, separated by columns.

We can always change it to how you need it, but your desired output wasnt detailed.

You could also do something like this:

```
$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE  CONCAT(id_user,fname,lname,location,email,phone_number,username) LIKE '%".$query."%'");

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<li>";
    foreach($data_fetch as $row => $value){
        echo "Row: $row - $value<br />";
    }
    echo "</li><hr/>";
}
```

Comment: when I put that in place of mine the whole thing wouldn't work, I got a blank page

Comment: second block, when I paste it in and refresh my page it goes blank

Comment: the first block does this.....1,1,Megan,Megan,Megan,Megan,Jersey Shore,Jersey Shore,admin@pizzatogo.com,admin@pizzatogo.com,6836656336,6836656336,megan,megan,99c307a7bcd9067efb2967906eef4b87,                                 all on one line, getting closer but not pretty

Comment: How would you like the data to be displayed?

Comment: in some kind order with titles. and without the last two columns, these are the passwords, I wont need to display them

Comment: Then the second option is what you are looking for. Try again, see if it works now

Comment: Its not working, every time I put it in then refresh my page it blanks out.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The above is tested and working on local setup. Enable `error_reporting(9);` and if it's still blank, you have a Parser Error.

Comment: add that line, `error_reporting(9);` at the top of your code, after `<?php`

Comment: Awsome, that did the trick. Thank you. Now if I can just figure out how to redirect the admin to that page I will be done. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark your questions as answered to help keep the site organized.